# how to get name of the image which is just taken from camera?

Tags: java, android

As the title says, I want to get the name of the file which is just taken from camera. I have a full path of the image such as like this `sdcard\image.jpg`. So how can I get image.jpg name in android? Any sample code would be helpful.

**Update**

OR How can I simply get the name of the photo which is just taken from the camera? It doesnt matter if I know the path of the image.

Comment: you want read all photo's (taken from camera) on sdcard?

Comment: no I already have the path of the image in a string variable. Now I just need to get that name from that path.

Comment: I took that image from camera

Comment: you want get image details from path?

Comment: just name of the Image. let say image name is 321321321.jpg. SO this is what I want 321321321.jpg

Comment: you want to get last image name for taken camera?

Comment: if your know full path of you image file then File.getName() works for you..

Comment: @user370305 how can I use this method? any example please

Comment: See also [get the last picture taken by user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337585/get-the-last-picture-taken-by-user)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

In onActivityResult() method:

```
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                path=getLastImagePath();      
                int dotposition= path.lastIndexOf("/");
                imageName = path.substring(dotposition + 1, path.length());
```

This will give you the path of the last image in "path" variable and image name in "imageName" variable.