# How to get last taken picture Uri

Tags: android, path, uri, android-camera, android-edittext

- ***I'm trying to take a picture with android camera intent and get this
  picture's location to edit text to use in the future for uploading it. How do I take the last taken picture Uri to my edit text for future use ? ***

**opening intent for taking a picture :**

```
Intent camera_intent = new Intent(

android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

startActivityForResult(camera_intent, ACTIVITY_CAMERA);
```

**getting activity for result:**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == ACTIVITY_CAMERA)) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            my_image.setImageBitmap(photo);
            data.putExtra("Camera", true);
        }
```

Comment: if you want to get the last picture taken by user, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337585/get-the-last-picture-taken-by-user