# Get the 1st image in Gallery

Tags: android

How do I get the 1st image in the Gallery folder?

I want to browse the Gallery folder and access the 1st image.

I looked at getContentResolver().query but there doesn't seem to be a way to use the method without giving the Uri.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8557147/909497) is an answer for getting the newest picture from gallery. Maybe you can modify it. Hope this helps.