# Android Gallery Button Beside Capture Button

Tags: android

can you plesae tell me what can I use to make the gallery widget that is on the left side of the capture button. I am guessing I would need access to the last image captured and an image view and then the person would be taken to the gallery to select the image. Can you please tell me how I should go about that and any references to websites or documentation? [image: Screen Design]

Comment: I think you need to implement custom camera

Comment: Can you also please tell me how I can enable the user to select an area of the image that is shown on an Image View.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337585/get-the-last-picture-taken-by-user). There is answer how to get last picture taken by user and then you can simply set it to your ImageView.