# get latest image android studio programmically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I've recently been writing a program on android studio that extract call log and contacts from phone and stores it in firebase realtime database. Does anyone know how to extract latest image from gallery and store it in firebase storage?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

am new at android ,
i use this to  upload image to firebase storage
imageUri  is the path of the image upload from the gallery
and imageUrl is the path of the image in firebase storage

```
 public String getExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(contentResolver.getType(uri));
}

private void uploadImage() {
    final StorageReference reference = mStorageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getExtension(imageUri));
    reference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                            new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                //to get the path of the image in the firebase storage
                                    String imageUrl = uri.toString();
                         
                                }
                            }
                    );
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: and check that it may help u https://stackoverflow.com/a/8557147/14137110

Comment: Thank you, with a bit of tweaking it worked!!!