# Force open camera on action_get_content intent to avoid some bugs

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

When using the following code to select a picture from my gallery, I also have the option to take a new picture, when I do it saves it (in the default image gallery) and I can select that image.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                PICK_IMAGE);
```

My ultimate goal is to have two options "select from gallery" and "take picture".  My question - is there a way to boot the camera automatically via the above Intent, possibly with some extras?

And I don't mean using the camera intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
```

While testing with the camera intent I have been running into two main bugs: [Ok button bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent) and the small image return, so I was wondering if my other method is possible.  Probably not, but its worth a shot..?

Comment: Eh, the more I think about it - its probably a horrible idea because they won't have the "select image by clicking ok" functionality.  Still curious if its possible though.

Comment: Hmm..I guess its not doable.  Back to IMAGE_CAPTURE, good, great, grand, wonderful - no yelling on the bus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the answer is no.  The best method is getting the `Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");` to play nicely.  Even if it were possible, the user interaction would be unintuitive and confusing as there would be no "accept photo" button/interaction.