# Android mkdir not making folder

Tags: android, mkdir

Tonight I am currently having issues doing something that I thought would be simple... making a folder in /mnt/sdcard.

I have set the follow permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

My `Main.java` has the following to make the folder:

```
public class Main extends TabActivity {
    static int index = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "Main";       

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + "/tallgrass/images");
        boolean success = false;
        if(!folder.exists()){
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        if (!success){ 
            Log.d(TAG,"Folder not created.");
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG,"Folder created!");
        }
    }
```

I get the "Folder created!" message in my log but when I check both `/mnt/sdcard` and `/sdcard` neither one has the folder. I have tried calling:

```
Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())
```

and it returns true. I just can't figure this one out because all signs are pointing that it should work. I have also tried it with the phone disconnected from the PC in case the SD card was mounting or something as I am currently using my phone instead of the emulator for developing. Speaking of which, does `debuggable` to `true` maybe prevent it from making the folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Does the `/mnt/sdcard/tallgrass/` directory exist? (I'm guessing not, but you never know.)

The [`File.mkdirs()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) method will create all needed directories; `mkdir()` will only create the *last* directory in the pathname.

Comment: That's it! I was trying to post an answer as i figured that out moments after I posted but being a new user it wouldn't let me answer my own post. I will check this as soon as it lets me. Thanks!

Comment: D'oh! Mostly the automated enforcements here are reasonable enough (and very effective at knocking down spam), but new users sometimes bear the brunt of those restrictions. Anyway, welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check where you are putting the permissions they must go in this way:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="edu.una.info.app">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="edu.una.info.SplashScreenActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Different Device. The problem exists with my Emulator Device, but when I connected my **Oneplus 5T**, it created a Folder (My Oneplus Does not have a External MicroSD).

But at the same time, my emulator (**Pixel 3**) does not create a Folder at all.

At least the Permissions are all good.