# How to create a folder "beam" on SDcard ("/ sdcard / beam")

Tags: java, android, directory

I need to create a folder "BEAM" on the SD card, but it says to me that the folder cannot be created.

I used this code:

```
    File mediaDir = new File("/sdcard/beam");
        / / Create a folder if not exists
        if (!mediaDir.exists()) {
            mediaDir.mkdir(); // this code return false
        }
```

Is folder "beam" protected?

I have also this Android permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: are you testing the app on an emulator?

Comment: You don't want to hardcode the entire path. Use File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. Do not use hardcore string like **'sdcard'** or **'mnt/sdcard'**

```
File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),File.separator+"beam/");
f.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not always at the same location, try using

> Environment.getExternalStorageState() returns path to internal SD mount point like "/mnt/sdcard"

For example my phone location would be /storage/sdcard0/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code

```
 if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                 android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

                 File f = new File(
                         Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "beam");
                 f.mkdirs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create the folder using 'adb shell' and then 'mkdir /sdcard/beam'? It should work fine. If it's not, you should get and idea, what's wrong. Also, don't hardcode sdcard folder. See:

[Creating a directory in /sdcard fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853472/creating-a-directory-in-sdcard-fails)

[Android mkdir not making folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958600/android-mkdir-not-making-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, only you are missing a `/` after beam word, add it and try again like following code,

```
File mediaDir = new File("/sdcard/beam/");  // / is added after beam
// Create a folder if not exists
if (!mediaDir.exists()) 
{
     mediaDir.mkdir(); // this code return false
}
```