# List of 10.1in Android Tablets with/without the Camera Intent bug

Tags: android, camera, crash

Does anyone have a list of the 10.1in Android tablets with/without the camera intent bug mentioned here: [Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent)

I seem to be getting this bug on the Xoom.