# How to get the path to the last image captured by Android camera?

Tags: android, camera

I am using the built-in camera in my Android app and having problems getting the path to the last captured image.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ....
}
```

`Intent data` contains a thumbnail of the last captured image, not the actual image saved to the SD card. So, how do I get the path to the actual full size image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer is probably what you are looking for:

[How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android/2508138#2508138)

Alternatively, you could set the path for the picture manually before starting the Camera activity. You could add this path like this:

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(FILE_PATH));
```

Then on the result, you check if the resultCode is RESULT_OK, and use the path of the image you already know.

Comment: Oh, I do know about MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT solution, but that way I'd have to save an extra copy of the image on the SD card and then delete it when I am done processing it.

Comment: What about the answer I linked to, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Wouldn't I have to open the gallery that way and make the user pick an image?

Comment: requestCode might be a different one but the rest of the code should work.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent/1932268#1932268 It looks like there is a bug with certain Android devices, you might be careful, or just save the image to a specific path that you know.