# I cannot return the previous activity with using ActivityForResult

Tags: android, image-capture

I have these codes. Camera opened, the picture is taken, but when I click on "ok" button, nothing happened. The only way to get back to previous activity is clicking the "x" button which is not useful for me :). What is the problem? (onActivityResult method is not finished yet.) (I used to use this algorithm with **Android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** intent. there was everything OK. I have no idea why I have problem now.)

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            db.open();
            Cursor cr = db.getAllRecords();
            int count = cr.getCount();

            db.close();

            File cameraFolder;

            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TSFC");
            else
                cameraFolder= ShowMessagesPage.this.getCacheDir();
            if(!cameraFolder.exists())
                cameraFolder.mkdirs();

            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TSFC/" + (count + 1) + ".jpg");
            getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));

            initialURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);

            startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, CAMERA_RESULT);
        }});}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
          Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            photo = (Uri) extras.get("data");


        }
      }
```

Comment: Ok, I think you have to remove this code line,  `getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));` and let me know what happen then I will tell you whats the problem.

Comment: use this Link for more detail http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera/

Comment: have a FATAL EXCEPTION : Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Comment: Ok, so now you are coming on `onActivityResult()` right? after press OK Button which is previously not worked..

Comment: Cannot go because of error but yes, the "ok" button works now... So, what's the problem :/ still cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Its well known Bug,

Just Add this code line, `photo.createNewFile();`

Something like,

```
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TSFC/" + (count + 1) + ".jpg");
photo.createNewFile();
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
```

Also don't forget to,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And let me know your progress.

Comment: I have a link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent

Comment: No way... Still not working... I will take a look at the link you posted. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Use `onActivityResult(..)` Method to get back Result Like this Way.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
        // Make sure the request was successful

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            photo = (Uri) extras.get("data");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No change. Still not going back when I clicked on the "ok" button.