# Camera Force Closing issue in Samsung Galaxy S3 version 4.1.1

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, galaxy, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I want to capture image and save it in Image view in one of My Application. I  already have an idea how to implement it and also Works fine in all device  Except Samsung Galaxy S3.

**What I Want:** Avoid the Force Closing Issue Coming in Samsung Galaxy S3 and probably for all other Device which i have not yet tested.

**What I have Done:** I have Done the Below Code to achieve my goal.

BuildInukshk_4 Activity :

```
package com.inukshk.CreateInukshk;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.inukshk.R;
import com.inukshk.constant.ImageCurve;

public class BuildInukshk_4 extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnDismissListener {

    String TAG = "BuildInukshk_4";
    Button btn_back, btn_upload_picture;
    TextView txt_next;

    public static Activity BuildInukshk_4Activity;

    // Upload Camera
    public static String media = null;
    public static String media_thumb = null;
    public static String media_type = null;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    String _path, Place = "";
    ImageView imageView;
    boolean flag = true;
    Uri uriVideo = null, mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath = "";
    Uri selectedImageUri = null;
    private String filemanagerstring;
    Bitmap mBitmap;

    // From Transperant
    ContentResolver crThumb;
    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2500, VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
    final static int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED = 2;
    BitmapFactory.Options options;
    String fileName;
    long id, imageid;
    Cursor cursor, cursorimage, thumbCursor;

    private String selectedthumbpath = "";
    boolean finish = false;
    // ADDED12324
    // private String filemanagerstring;

    Bitmap curThumb = null, curThumb1 = null;
    String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID };

    String[] mediaColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

    String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buildinukshk_4);

        BuildInukshk_4Activity = this;
        btn_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_upload_picture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_upload_picture);
        btn_upload_picture.setOnClickListener(this);

        txt_next = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_next);
        txt_next.setOnClickListener(this);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_upload_pic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v == txt_next) {
            if (selectedImagePath.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(BuildInukshk_4.this,
                        "Please Upload Picture First", 3).show();
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(BuildInukshk_4.this,
                        BuildInukshk_5.class));
            }

            // this.finish();
        } else if (v == btn_back) {
            // startActivity(new Intent(BuildInukshk_4.this,
            // BuildInukshk_3.class));
            this.finish();
        } else if (v == btn_upload_picture) {
            registerForContextMenu(btn_upload_picture);
            openContextMenu(btn_upload_picture);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside onCreateContextMenu");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        if (v == btn_upload_picture) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Upload Media");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Photo");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (item.getTitle() == "Photo") {
            media_type = "image";
            // media_thumb = null;
            /*
             * Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
             * Transperant.class); intent.putExtra("MEDIA_TYPE", media_type);
             * startActivity(intent);
             */

            ImageChooseOptionDialog();
            // ImageChooseOptionDialog();

        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Transperant Class
    private void ImageChooseOptionDialog() {

        // finish = true;

        Log.i(TAG, "Inside ImageChooseOptionDialog");
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuildInukshk_4.this).create();
        dialog.setTitle("Upload Photo");
        dialog.setMessage("Choose your Photo From here.");
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(this);
        dialog.setButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // dialog.dismiss();
                Log.i(TAG, "Inside ImageChooseOptionDialog inside camera");

                Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageState().equals(
                                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
                mCapturedImageURI = null;
                if (isSDPresent) {
                    // yes SD-card is present
                    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
                    long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize()
                            * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
                    long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
                    Log.e("", "Available MB : " + megAvailable);
                    if (megAvailable > 2) {
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        _path = cal.getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg";

                        String fileName = _path;
                        // File file = new File(_path);
                        // mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);

                        mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                values);

                        Log.d(TAG, "----- path ----- " + _path);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                mCapturedImageURI);

                        Log.d(TAG, "----- mCapturedImageURI ******----- "
                                + mCapturedImageURI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1212);

                        flag = false;
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(BuildInukshk_4.this,
                                "No Memory Available", 2).show();
                        flag = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Sorry
                    // StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                    // .getPath());
                    // long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize()
                    // * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
                    // long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
                    // Log.e("", "Internal MB : " + megAvailable);
                    // if (megAvailable > 2) {
                    // startActivityForResult(new Intent(Transperant.this,
                    // VideoRecorder.class), REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
                    //
                    // flag = false;
                    // } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BuildInukshk_4.this, "No Memory Available",
                            2).show();
                    flag = true;
                    // }
                    // Toast.makeText(Transperant.this, "No External Storage",
                    // 2)
                    // .show();
                }

            }
        });
        dialog.setButton2("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Inside Gallary");
                Log.i(TAG, "Inside ImageChooseOptionDialog inside camera");
                // dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
                flag = false;

            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            final Intent data) {

        crThumb = getContentResolver();
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 1;
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside onActivityResult");

        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "SELECT_PICTURE");
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                // filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    BuildInukshk_4.media = selectedImagePath;
                    Log.e("Image path", selectedImagePath);

                    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(media);
                    if (mBitmap != null) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Inside Set Image");
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                    }
                    // selectedthumbpath = null;
                    // Testimage();

                    // // curThumb1 = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    // // crThumb, imageid,
                    // // MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
                    //
                    // Cursor thumbCursorimage = managedQuery(
                    // MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    // imageColumns, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
                    // + "=" + imageid, null, null);
                    //
                    // Log.e("Transarerant",
                    // "--- inside do TEst Image cusor 2nd -- "
                    // + thumbCursorimage.getCount());
                    // if (thumbCursorimage.moveToFirst()) {
                    // selectedthumbpath = thumbCursorimage
                    // .getString(thumbCursorimage
                    // .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                    // // selectedthumbpath = new
                    // Log.e("PathofThumb", selectedthumbpath);
                    // BuildInukshk_4.media_thumb = selectedthumbpath;
                    // }

                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        }

        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED) {
        }

        else if (requestCode == 1212) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Inside IF CONDITIONS in Camera");
                Log.i(TAG, "mCptureURI :" + mCapturedImageURI);

                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection,
                        null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                Log.e("Image path", selectedImagePath);

                BuildInukshk_4.media = selectedImagePath;

                mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(media);
                if (mBitmap != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Inside Set Image");
                    // mBitmap = ImageCurve.GetCurveImage(mBitmap);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                }

                // selectedthumbpath = null;
                // Testimage();

                // curThumb1 =
                // MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb,
                // imageid, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                // options);
                //
                // Cursor thumbCursorimage = managedQuery(
                // MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                // imageColumns, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
                // + "=" + imageid, null, null);
                //
                // Log.e("Transarerant",
                // "--- inside do TEst Image cusor 2nd -- "
                // + thumbCursorimage.getCount());
                // if (thumbCursorimage.moveToFirst()) {
                // selectedthumbpath = thumbCursorimage
                // .getString(thumbCursorimage
                // .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                // // selectedthumbpath = new
                // Log.e("PathofThumb", selectedthumbpath);
                // BuildInukshk_4.media_thumb = selectedthumbpath;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Also Here is my Manifest file if i have done my mistake here:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.inukshk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- FOR Camera -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <!-- Don't require camera, as this requires a rear camera. This allows it to work on the Nexus 7 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_final"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WhereAmI.WhereAmI"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WhosNearMe.WhosNearMe"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WhatsNearMe.WhatsNearMe"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateInukshk.CreateInukshk"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateInukshk.BuildInukshk_1"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateInukshk.BuildInukshk_2"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateInukshk.BuildInukshk_3"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateInukshk.BuildInukshk_4"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateInukshk.BuildInukshk_5"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".tTab.TabSample"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".register.RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Transperant"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AfterSplash"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".login.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.MyProfile"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.MyInterests"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.InukshkSettings"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.MyPicture"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.MyInukshks"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".settings.ChangePassword"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have searched for this issue in Many SO link but do not quite get any solution worked for me. Please Help me to get out of this.

**I would like to make a note here that I do not have a real device for testing this issue.

But my client has this issue on a real device. I have made an emulator which is the same as S3 and its working with no worries in every scenarios.
 I do not know why this is happening only on the real device.**

Thanks in Advance

> **EDITED :** iI have solved the above issue by modifying the below code and put as an answer. You can have a look after reading the question.

Comment: @GabeSechan: Thnks for your Support. but as i have said that i do not have real device.and i am not getting any error while capturing image in emulator and in any real device which i have. but Client having issue while capturing image only in samsung galaxy S3.

Comment: Just look at these code `String fileName = _path;
File file = new File(fileName); if(!file.exist()) file.createNewFile();` It will surely solve your problems. You have to make file before passing its Uri to Camera Intent. Try this and let me know what happen..

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295906/i-cannot-return-the-previous-activity-with-using-activityforresult/14296227#14296227

Comment: @Bhavesh: If users have submitted the Force Close report/s, you can grab them from the Developer Console.

Comment: @Bhavesh: If you want someone to try and run this, post your whole project somewhere and link it. I'll run it on an S3 for you and let you know what happens.

Comment: I have Found the Answer and Put here as an Answer. everyone can try it out once if it helps you. thanks all for your very well supports.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have Spent many Hours for this Single Issue and Got the Code Working in Most of the Devices With Modifying the Code as Below :

Any one having the Same issue in future can try out the Below Code.

While Calling intent for Image Capture :

```
String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

                    if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, filename);
                        mImageCaptureUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                values);

                        intent.putExtra(
                                android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                mImageCaptureUri);


                        try {

                            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(BuildInukshk_4_Camera.this)
                                .setMessage(
                                        "External Storeage (SD Card) is required.\n\nCurrent state: "
                                                + storageState)
                                .setCancelable(true).create().show();
                    }

                } else { // pick from file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
```

Inside OnActivityResult Method :

```
case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                Log.i("TAG", "Inside PICK_FROM_CAMERA");

                // Final Code As Below
                try {
                    Log.i("TAG", "inside Samsung Phones");
                    String[] projection = {
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, // The columns we want
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };
                    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "=" + // Select
                                                                                    // only
                                                                                    // mini's
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;

                    String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";

                    // At the moment, this is a bit of a hack, as I'm returning ALL
                    // images, and just taking the latest one. There is a better way
                    // to
                    // narrow this down I think with a WHERE clause which is
                    // currently
                    // the selection variable
                    Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            projection, selection, null, sort);

                    long imageId = 0l;
                    long thumbnailImageId = 0l;
                    String thumbnailPath = "";

                    try {
                        myCursor.moveToFirst();
                        imageId = myCursor
                                .getLong(myCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
                        thumbnailImageId = myCursor
                                .getLong(myCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
                        thumbnailPath = myCursor
                                .getString(myCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                    } finally {
                        // myCursor.close();
                    }

                    // Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image

                    String[] largeFileProjection = {
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };

                    String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID
                            + " DESC";
                    myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
                    String largeImagePath = "";

                    try {
                        myCursor.moveToFirst();

                        // This will actually give yo uthe file path location of the
                        // image.
                        largeImagePath = myCursor
                                .getString(myCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
                        mImageCaptureUri_samsung = Uri.fromFile(new File(
                                largeImagePath));
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    } finally {
                        // myCursor.close();
                    }

                    // These are the two URI's you'll be interested in. They give
                    // you a
                    // handle to the actual images
                    Uri uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            String.valueOf(imageId));
                    Uri uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));

                    // I've left out the remaining code, as all I do is assign the
                    // URI's
                    // to my own objects anyways...
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    mImageCaptureUri_samsung = null;
                    Log.i("TAG",
                            "inside catch Samsung Phones exception " + e.toString());

                }

                try {
                    Log.i("TAG",
                            "URI Samsung:" + mImageCaptureUri_samsung.getPath());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Excfeption inside Samsung URI :" + e.toString());
                }

                try {

                    Log.i("TAG", "URI Normal:" + mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Excfeption inside Normal URI :" + e.toString());
                }



                break;
```

After Running Below Code you Will get Two URIs `mImageCaptureUri_samsung` and `mImageCaptureUri`

you will get the mImageCaptureUri as your Path if you are running the App with  Simple Devices and you will get your Cpatured Image path in mImageCaptureUri_samsung if you are running with Devices Like Samsung Galaxy S3.

Further you all can go ahead with your Code. it Works For me Very Fine With all the Devices i have tested on.

Also if Someone is having Problem with Above Code than they can reference the Below Great Link [Solution of Samsung Galaxy S3](http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/)

Hope it will Help.

Comment: Thank you, but you posted something like 500 lines of code here.  Can you do anything to pinpoint the specific issue and fix?

Comment: @gcl1 :Thnks for your Suggestions. I have Updated my Answer Now .

Comment: I read through the code and reference you gave.  Where/how do test to determine which URI to use (mImageCaptureUri vs. mImageCaptureUri_samsung)?

Comment: @gcl1: after capturing the Picture you just have to check whether 'mImageCaptureUri_samsung==null' or Not? and if yes than only you will have to Use 'mImageCaptureUri' URI. I hope its been Clear to you. let me know if you are still having any kind of Problem.

Comment: @Bhavesh I am stuck on the same issue. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: @Korhan: Yes Sure. what is the Problem you are facing?

Comment: @Bhavesh I am unable to port this code according to my present code. I am sure you can easily get this by looking at my code? Would you mind coming to one of the Stack Overflow chat rooms or should I do anything to show my code?

Comment: Sure. we can extend our talk http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era

Comment: @Bhavesh can you please help me with my code too. I am dealing with multiple photos. it works fine with other phones but having problem with samsung galaxy S3.