# camera intent data null in onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) in Samsung S3

Tags: android

**Problem:** I am getting camera intent's data null in  `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`  in Samsung S3. But working well on some other devices. I customized my code for getting data and searched this issue in web but nothing found useful.

**Code :**

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == TAKE_CAMERA && data != null && data.getData() != null)  

           else if (requestCode == TAKE_CAMERA) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setDataAndType(tempFileUri, "image/*");

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 90);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 90);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_CAMERA);
    } else if (requestCode == CROP_CAMERA && data != null) {
        Bitmap photo = data.getExtras().getParcelable("data");
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFileUri.getPath());
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photo != null) {
            imagePhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);

            <my code>
        }

    }
```

Comment: Put your LOGCAT data here. I had facing same issues with s3 before it will fix through putting This permission in AndroidMenifest.xml file     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: unfortunately am not getting any log cat when image not loads. There is also sd card permission in my Menifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Faced the Same Issue and got Work around with Below Way it will definitely  help you tr it out once :

For the Solution i have referred below link for solve the issue :

[Camera Solution for Samsung Galaxy S3](http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/)

Write  the Below Code While calling captured image :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

And Get your URI by Below way inside OnActivityResult() Method:

```
if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            Log.i("TAG", "Inside PICK_FROM_CAMERA");


            // Describe the columns you'd like to have returned. Selecting from
            // the Thumbnails location gives you both the Thumbnail Image ID, as
            // well as the original image ID

            try {
                Log.i("TAG", "inside Samsung Phones");
                String[] projection = {
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, // The columns we want
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };
                String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "=" + // Select
                                                                                // only
                                                                                // mini's
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;

                String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";

                // At the moment, this is a bit of a hack, as I'm returning ALL
                // images, and just taking the latest one. There is a better way
                // to
                // narrow this down I think with a WHERE clause which is
                // currently
                // the selection variable
                Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, selection, null, sort);

                long imageId = 0l;
                long thumbnailImageId = 0l;
                String thumbnailPath = "";

                try {
                    myCursor.moveToFirst();
                    imageId = myCursor
                            .getLong(myCursor
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
                    thumbnailImageId = myCursor
                            .getLong(myCursor
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
                    thumbnailPath = myCursor
                            .getString(myCursor
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                } finally {
                    // myCursor.close();
                }

                // Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image

                String[] largeFileProjection = {
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };

                String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID
                        + " DESC";
                myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
                String largeImagePath = "";

                try {
                    myCursor.moveToFirst();

                    // This will actually give yo uthe file path location of the
                    // image.
                    largeImagePath = myCursor
                            .getString(myCursor
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(
                            largeImagePath));

                } finally {
                    // myCursor.close();
                }
                // These are the two URI's you'll be interested in. They give
                // you a
                // handle to the actual images
                Uri uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        String.valueOf(imageId));
                Uri uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));

                // I've left out the remaining code, as all I do is assign the
                // URI's
                // to my own objects anyways...
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.i("TAG",
                        "inside catch Samsung Phones exception " + e.toString());

            }


            try {

                Log.i("TAG", "URI Normal:" + mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Excfeption inside Normal URI :" + e.toString());
            }

            //doCrop();

            break;
```

Comment: @Akhilesh Mani: got the Solution?

Comment: Hi Bhavesh this not working in my side. After capturing image image, mobile orientation changes automatically and my uri gets null. I also stored that uri externally but this also not working.

Comment: @AkhileshMani: have you set inside menifest file this line  'android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"' for that activity and if not add it and also call onConfiguratiochanged() method for it.

Comment: you can look [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495304/camera-force-closing-issue-in-samsung-galaxy-s3-version-4-1-1/14640678#14640678) my answer with full java file. you will better idea there.

Answer (score 3):

if you are providing MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, then the intent is null, but you will have the photo in the file you provided (Uri.fromFile(f)).

I hope below link give the solution for you.It working for me.

http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/02/multiple-choose-custom-gallery.html

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by telling the camera activity to save the image on SD card:

```
tempImageNameUri = "some temporary name";
i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,tempImageNameUri);
i.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(i,SOME_CONSTANT);
```

and when the called activity finished, in `onActivityResult` take the item from SD card from the temporary path and use it.

Comment: Could you Also include the code for getting something from the SD card?

Answer (score 0):

You might have got the solution to your question but this would help someone. Below is the blog link created by `Commonsware` which is about cropping of image after photo is taken. In which he said using action `com.android.camera.action.CROP` might not work perfect in all different kind of devices.

Here is the [Link](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html)