# Android custom camera issue in some devices

Tags: android, performance, android-camera

Hi, I have a custom camera where I have click button, when clicked it captures the image... Everything is fine but in some devices the preview is stretching and also the preview is overlaying half the screen and flickering... some wierd unwanted effect. How to fix this?

This is my code:

Camera Activity:

```
preview = new Preview(this, (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));

preview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);

buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        // camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }
});
```

Preview class:

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Preview(Context context, SurfaceView sv) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = sv;
        // addView(mSurfaceView);

        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {

            // get Camera parameters
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

            mSupportedPreviewSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();

            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                // set the focus mode
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                // set Camera parameters
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0, (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2, width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have same issues in Sony Xperia

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh, Do you have McAfee Antivirus installed on your phone? http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/47893?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh, Actually, you must have McAfee installed already since it comes pre-installed on Sony Xperia. Read the link to the thread fully. This solution may not solve Sukamo's problem, since he didn't tell us which phones were being affected, but it should solve yours at least.

Comment: @sukarno, If none of the answers worked for you, please tell us your minimum api level, the api level you're targeting, and the actual model names/api levels of the devices that are showing this problem with your app.

Comment: Hi Have you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

There is a known bug happening on some devices for the image captures described here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1480

Not sure if your problem is the same, but you should try the code explained in this answer from another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1932268/2206688

Answer (score 1):

McAfee Antivirus may be the culprit in this [case](http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/47893?start=0&tstart=0).

In which case, uninstalling it should solve the issue.