# save image captured in SD card

Tags: android, image-capture

```
    private void takeNewPicture() {  

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);  

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");  
    cameraImagePath = getContentResolver().insert(  
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);      
    //  cameraImagePath=  cameraImagePath+"/temp";  
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraImagePath);  
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);  
}
```

i used above code to capture and save image.but i need to change the path where file is saved(In SD CARD).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
//SD card "root" directory
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

or

```
//SD card directory for pictures
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Comment: hello i wud be more glad if you can eloborate the answer.because i m new to android

Comment: I think this answer should be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent