# translate android java to xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, webview, xamarin, translate

I'm trying to make an android app with a webview which can upload images to a html page.
I think i found a solution here: [Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent/1932268#1932268)
but i'm having trouble translating everything to Xamarin c#, any can help me here? the code i'm interestet in is:

```
       File imageDirectory = new File("/sdcard/signifio");
       String path = imageDirectory.toString().toLowerCase();
       String name = imageDirectory.getName().toLowerCase();


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put(Media.TITLE, "Image"); 
        values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, path.hashCode());
        values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,name);

        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image capture by camera");
       values.put("_data", "/sdcard/signifio/1111.jpg");
     uri = getContentResolver().insert( Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI , values);
        Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"); 

        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

more specific it's what classes i have to import to find Media.TITLE, Images.Media.BUCKET_ID.... and so forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Android.Provider.MediaStore

If they aren't in their you could use the actual strings instead, see [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html#BUCKET_ID)

Here's the call to getContentResolver Xamarin style:

```
this.ContentResolver.Insert(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, values);
```

For the location of the file use:

```
Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures), "CameraAppDemo");
```

There is a recipe for using a camera intent in the [Xamarin documentation.](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/)

Comment: NICE... thanks. i couldn't find them, but i use the string instead.
what about the getContentResolver().insert function, and Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI cant find them anywhere...

Comment: So... i got one more question. i'm trying to find a place to store an image which the camera has taken. it has to be a place where both my app and the camera app have acecs to.
i was thinking about.
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
but i do not know where to find that in xamarin, or another even better place to put it? :) can you help me again?. thanks...