# The IMAGE_CAPTURE can not return back in some android devices

Tags: android

I need to take photos in my application, this is the core codes:

tigger:

```
mPhotoToBeUpload = new File(mImageBasePath, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
try {
    mPhotoToBeUpload.mkdirs();
    mPhotoToBeUpload.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("xx",e.getMessage());
}

Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mPhotoToBeUpload);

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Result_Code_Camera);
```

Result handler:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photoTaken = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPhotoToBeUpload.getAbsolutePath());
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(photoTaken);
    } else
}
```

However I found that these codes work in some devices but not in some others.

For example, they does not work in Nexus 4 and Nexus5.

While I saythey does not work,I mean that after I take a picture, and hit the `OK` button, I cannot get back to the previous activity:

[image]

It have no effect when I hit the `OK`(the icon inside the red circle).

What is the problem?

---

Upadte:

```
private final String mImageBasePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + IConstant.Application_Folder + File.separator + "photos";
mPhotoToBeUpload = new File(mImageBasePath, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
```

Result: `mPhotoToBeupLoad=/storage/emulated/0/myapp/photos/1395287647386.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by referring this question:[Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent)

Instead of

```
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mPhotoToBeUpload);

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Result_Code_Camera);
```

Use:

```
URI mPhotoToBeUploadURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoToBeUploadURI);
```

Answer (score 0):

Show what is your path for mImageBasePath, because this problem mostly happen when the file path is invalid.

Comment: you can try copying and pasting this to your codes and see if it works.

mPhotoToBeUpload = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myapp" + File.separator + "photos" + File.separator " + "1395287647386.png");


Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mPhotoToBeUpload);

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Result_Code_Camera);