# Save picture EXTRA_OUPUT is empty onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I have on fragment loaded in an activity.

Inside this fragment, i set an event onClick to a button to take a picture. I want to save this picture inside internal storage in a specific folder.

This is my fragment class, i've tried a lot of different solutions but i can't understand why mCurrentPhotoPath is created but not filled by the picture taken (SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null).

This is my fragment class (i removed some part of code)

```
public class Q3Fragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private Spinner field;
private int TAB_ID = 1;
private int Q_ID = 3;

private final static String DEBUG_TAG = "PHOTOMANAGER";
private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private ImageView imagePreview;
private String filePath = "";
Intent takePictureIntent;
private PhotoManager pm;

public static Q3Fragment newInstance(String type) {
    Q3Fragment fragment = new Q3Fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("type", type);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
public Q3Fragment() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_q3, container, false);


    /////////////

    imagePreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.q4imgPreview);



    takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    Button buttonPhoto = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.q4BtnPhoto);
    buttonPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 11);
            }


        }

    });

    /////////////

    return view;

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Boolean valid,int qId);
}






@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent data) {
    Log.d("Fragment PHOTOMANAGER","onActivityResult");
    // lors du resultat de l'intent (lorsqu'on clique sur save la photo)

    try {
        handleSmallCameraPhoto();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(data != null) {
        getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(data.getData(), null, null);
    }


}


// on enregistre la photo
private void handleSmallCameraPhoto() throws IOException {


    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

    if(f.exists()){
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"FILE EXISTS " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
    }

    // here the bitmap not containing picture.
    Bitmap mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), contentUri);

    imagePreview.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    filePath = saveToInternalStorage(mBitmap);


}


// methode pour sauvegarder une photo (min ou full)
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"saveToInternalStorage");

    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir_"+getArguments().getString("type"), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String fileName;



    fileName = "q" + Q_ID + ".jpg";


    // Create imageDir
    File mypath = new File(directory, fileName);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"FILE SAVED "+mypath.getAbsolutePath());
    return mypath.getAbsolutePath();
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String imageFileName = "q" + Q_ID +"photo";
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"saveToInternalStorage");

    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir_"+getArguments().getString("type"), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            directory      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG," createcontainer file "+mCurrentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}


}
```

Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent

Comment: Try to load bitmap of your photo using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bitmapOptions)` instead of `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me mention a **key concept** in Android that's needed to understand why your code does not work as is. The `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent launches **another** app. In this case, a camera app to do a job. The `EXTRA_OUTPUT` tells the app called (i.e. the camera app) where to save the taken picture in the filesystem.

The problem is that apps may **only** access their **own** private internal storage. Thus, the camera app is not able to save the picture inside the caller's app (i.e. your app) private storage.

Note that you are calling `ContextWrapper.getDir` which points to a directory in your app's **private** storage.

If you want to store the picture in your app's private storage you will have to temporally store the image where it's accessible by both apps and `onActivityResult` copy the picture to your app's private storage.

Comment: Oh man.. you saved my day !!! The solution was just here near me, i thought about this problem but was focused on other useless things. Really thanks for your answer !