# Share files with appcelerator using android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, appcelerator

I try to share an file I downloaded. I put that file in the `Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory`. The file is saved correctly since i can show it in an `ImageView.image`.

Here's the code I use to start a android share intent:
(apparently you can not use the file:// scheme with android API 24. See this post: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623304/when-take-photo-get-java-lang-throwable-file-uri-exposed-through-clipdata))

```
filePath = filePath.replace('file','content');
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
});
intent.putExtraUri(Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM, filePath);
$.FileList.activity.startActivity(intent);
```

What happens is, the share dialog opens, I choose the app I wish to share to, but then I get a notice there is nothing to share.

*Screenshot of failed notification:*
[image: screenshot of failed notification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it was quite simple:

1. appcelerator handles the filePath by itself, so it is not necessary to replace **file** with **content**
2. the intent needs a type parameter.

the working code would be:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
  action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
  type: '*/*'
});
intent.putExtraUri(Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM, filePath);
$.FileList.activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
var Blob = $.container.toImage();
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, 'image_1.png');
f.write(Blob);


/// NOT HERE --filePath = filePath.replace('file','content');
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND
});
intent.putExtraUri(Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM, f.filePath);
////$.FileList.activity.startActivity(intent);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```