# Starting camera activity, app crashes

Tags: android, permissions, camera, crash

I have problem, that I have been searching for whole week. I'm creating app that sends photo and some data to server. The problem is that when I start activity, camera has to start but, for some devices app crashes. I cant describe the error because devices are in other cities. I have LG G3 and HUAWEI P7 on both of them works fine. I think this might be something wrong with permissions but I'm not sure.

```
package com.fishingtournaments.ZvejysZvejui;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.support.v4.os.EnvironmentCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;


public class SendImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 8675809;
    TextView fish_n, fish_s, points;
    public static final int REQUEST_CAPTURE = 1;
    public static String path;

    public String fish_name, fish_length, fish_points, colleague_id, fish_size, fish_photo, fish_id,
            user_id, user_name = "";


    //Declaring views
    private Button buttonUpload;
    private ImageView imageView;

    //storage permission code
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

    //Bitmap to get image from gallery

    //Uri to store the image uri
    private Uri imageUri; /*, uriSavedImage*/
    private File imagesFolder, image;
    private String fixedURI;


    //----------------------------------//

    // Storage for camera image URI components
    private final static String CAPTURED_PHOTO_PATH_KEY = "mCurrentPhotoPath";
    private final static String CAPTURED_PHOTO_URI_KEY = "uriSavedImage";

    // Required for camera operations in order to save the image file on resume.
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
    private Uri uriSavedImage = null;


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            savedInstanceState.putString(CAPTURED_PHOTO_PATH_KEY, mCurrentPhotoPath);
        }
        if (uriSavedImage != null) {
            savedInstanceState.putString(CAPTURED_PHOTO_URI_KEY, uriSavedImage.toString());
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(CAPTURED_PHOTO_PATH_KEY)) {
            mCurrentPhotoPath = savedInstanceState.getString(CAPTURED_PHOTO_PATH_KEY);
        }
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(CAPTURED_PHOTO_URI_KEY)) {
            uriSavedImage = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString(CAPTURED_PHOTO_URI_KEY));
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }


    //-++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+---//

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Requesting storage permission
        //TODO INTERFACE,
        //TODO CHECK PERMISSIONS
        //TODO TEST ON OTHER PHONES
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_image);
            buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_image);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SendImageActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
//                Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

                imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FishingTournament");
                image = new File(imagesFolder, "QR_" + timeStamp + ".png");
                uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CAPTURE);
            } else {
                String[] permissionRequest = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SendImageActivity.this, permissionRequest, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }


            buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }


    /*
    * This is the method responsible for image upload
    * We need the full image path and the name for the image in this method
    * */
    public void uploadMultipart() {

        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", "asd") //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .addParameter("colleague_id", colleague_id)
                    .addParameter("fish_length", fish_size)
                    .addParameter("fish_points", fish_points)
                    .addParameter("fish_photo", fish_photo)
                    .addParameter("fish_id", fish_id)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    //handling the image chooser activity result
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE) {
            if (data != null) {
                fixedURI = String.valueOf(uriSavedImage);
                fixedURI = fixedURI.replace("file://", "");
                path = fixedURI;
//                Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.getInstant().getCompressedBitmap(path);
//                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } else {

                fixedURI = String.valueOf(uriSavedImage);
                fixedURI = fixedURI.replace("file://", "");
                path = fixedURI;
//                Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.getInstant().getCompressedBitmap(path);
//                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }

        }

    }


    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }


    //Requesting permission
    private void requestStorageReadPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SendImageActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SendImageActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
            Toast.makeText(SendImageActivity.this, "Norint siųsti nuotrauką reikalingas leidimas prie failų saugyklos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SendImageActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    //This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            uploadMultipart();
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            onBackPressed();
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        final String user_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");
        final String colleague_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("colleague_id");
        final String user_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");
        Intent intent = new Intent(SendImageActivity.this, ChooseFishActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("colleague_id", colleague_id);
        intent.putExtra("user_name", user_name);
        intent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }

}
```

It might look dumb why I have if in onCreate() method, it's because in my LG G3 camera is restarting on taking photo. And thats why my onActivityResult() method looks strange.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fishingtournaments.ZvejysZvejui">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/descicon"
        android:label="Žvejys žvejui"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChooseFishActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ResultActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChooseFishActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowResultsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".SendImageActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

P.S. My code might look unclean, sorry for that, I have been doing everything and testing everything to solve that problem.

BTW I'm requesting permission for storage in my LoginActivity and there I'm creating folder for photos.

LoginActivity

```
package com.fishingtournaments.ZvejysZvejui;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;


    EditText qrCode_edit;
    Button check_button;
//  Button result_button;
    public String colleague_id;
    public String colleague_name;
    public String user_id, user_name;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Užklausa permissionų", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Norint siųsti nuotrauką reikalingas leidimas prie failų saugyklos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //And finally ask for the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Teisės suteiktos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/FishingTournament");
        if(!direct.exists()) {
            if (direct.mkdir())
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Direktorija sukurta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Nesukurta direktorija, nes ji jau egzistuoja", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
// it will create two folder in your internal storage first is specifyfoldername and another one inside the mentioned folder which is nestedfoldername


        qrCode_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qrCode_editText);
        check_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_button);
//      result_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.results);
        //QR Code
        final Activity activity = this;

        /**
         * Button for scanning QR code
         *
         */
        check_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                check_button.setEnabled(false);
                String qrCode = qrCode_edit.getText().toString();

                //QR Code
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Užveskite kamerą ant QR kodo");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();
                check_button.setEnabled(true);
                //---

                /*Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ChooseFishActivity.class);
                                colleague_id = jsonResponse.getString("colleague_id");
                                colleague_name = jsonResponse.getString("colleague_name");
                                user_id = jsonResponse.getString("user_id");
                                intent.putExtra("colleague_id",colleague_id);
                                intent.putExtra("user_name",colleague_name);
                                intent.putExtra("user_id",user_id);
                                startActivity(intent);
//                                finish();
                                //startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ChooseFishActivity.class));
                            }else{
                                String message = jsonResponse.getString("message");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                *//*ats.setText(message);*//*

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };


                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(qrCode, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);*/

            }
        });

        /**
         * Button for launching ShowResultsActivity
         */
        /*result_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ShowResultsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });*/

    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents()==null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Atšaukėte skanavimą", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            /*If correct QR-code*/
                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ChooseFishActivity.class);
                                colleague_id = jsonResponse.getString("colleague_id");
                                colleague_name = jsonResponse.getString("colleague_name");
                                user_id = jsonResponse.getString("user_id");
                                user_name = jsonResponse.getString("user_name");
                                intent.putExtra("colleague_id",colleague_id);
                                intent.putExtra("user_name",colleague_name);
                                intent.putExtra("user_id",user_id);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sveiki, " + user_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }else{
                                String message = jsonResponse.getString("message");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };


                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(result.getContents(), responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);


            }
        }else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your error logcat

Comment: Its hard to figure it out without log

Comment: Like I said, in my personal phones it works fine, but when I send my app to other people, and they try to test it, it crashes on camera intent.

Comment: it may cause by permissions .. try Android 6 > need permission to use camera

Comment: @ZeroOne I've been searching in internet how to do that, no luck tho. 
P.S. if I set minSdkVersion to 23 it drops parse error on some devices

Comment: have you add this in you manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`

Comment: @ZeroOne Added that line, still no luck.

Comment: show error log please..

Comment: @ZeroOne I can't because device is with other person in other city. I've tried to comment uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image); line in SendImageActivity. After that app is not crashing. But now I need to figure out how to save file in storage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out where the problem was.
The error was `exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()` . Basicly the problem was in this line `i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);`. After searching for this error I found solution in this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623304/when-take-photo-get-java-lang-throwable-file-uri-exposed-through-clipdata)