# Intent.ACTION_SEND targeting API Level 24+

Tags: java, android

I get `android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed` exception when trying to send a file with a Intent. It's my understanding that this is because I'm targeting 24> and `file://` is not supported anymore, `content://` should be used.

First I would like to say that I have seen similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623304/when-take-photo-get-java-lang-throwable-file-uri-exposed-through-clipdata) and i'v also seen [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) blog post.

But the problem is, all of the post refer to URI when taking a picture, in my case the file is saved successfully using Uri and now I want to send the image using Intent like below:

```
shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file://" + directoryToStore + "/" + filename);
            //the Uri above  - file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myPackageName/files/SavedImages/test.jpeg
            sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
        }
    });
```

By doing the above I only get a crash on some devices running 19>. Testing on my Samsung J7Pro (Android 7.0 API 24) I don't get a crash.

I have seen that some of that answers say that I can use:

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

But it's not the preferred way.

So, my question is. How should I handle sending files when targeting 24>. Should I do a if/else statement checking the version like `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {` and then use normal Uri for devices running <24 and how should I change `file://` to `content://`? I also don't understand why the crash only happens on some devices.

---

EDIT 1:

I have done what the answer below suggested but the file is not passed with the intent, instead I get a `Toast` saying `Unable to attach file` when I try to email the image.

Comment: Can you check your logcat and see what error / stacktrace you get?

Comment: @ArsenyLevin I'm not getting any errors, when I press the share button I only get `ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1` then I get the chooser where I can select a app to share the image with.

Comment: @ArsenyLevin I have logged `Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplication(),getApplication().getPackageName() + ". MyFileProvider", newFile);` and it returns `shared-files` instead of `SavedImages`

Comment: change the xml to be: `<files-path name="SavedImages" path="SavedImages/"/>`

Comment: @ArsenyLevin I still get the same Toast as my edit above. The Uri now returns `content://my.packahe.name.MyFileProvider/SavedImages/test.jpeg`

Comment: check my edit below. based on docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles

Comment: @ArsenyLevin Thank you for taking the time to reply, but I now get this error -`Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/my.package.name/files/SavedImages/test.jpeg`

Comment: sorry for the long ping-pong. try changing the xml element to be `<external-path` and NOT `<external-files-path` as I previously suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176512/discussion-between-hb-and-arseny-levin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to share files from your app is a `content provider`, specifically [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider).

Add your `FileProvider` to AnroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.MyFileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/shared_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Next, add the referenced resource, by adding an xml resource (Android Studio: right click on 'app' -> New -> Folder -> XML Resources fodler)
Then, inside this new folder create an xml file named `shared_paths.xml` (should match value in AndroidManifest.xml). Contents for `shared_paths.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="SavedImages" path="SavedImages/"/>
</paths>
```

EDIT: changed element type from `<files-path ../>` to `<external-path .. />` per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider). 
IMPORTANT: Change the `path` attribute to fit your needs.

Lastly change you code like this:

```
shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri screenshotUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".MyFileProvider", new File(directoryToStore, filename))
            //the Uri above  - file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myPackageName/files/SavedImages/test.jpeg
            sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using");
            chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you save your file in a public media folder in internal memory (i.e. for images  /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/my.package.name/SavedImages/myImage.jpg) you can also share the file via it-s content-media uri (for image content://media/external/images/media/4711).

This way you do not need your own FileProvider but the file is available for all.

With a lcoal FileProvider in apps' private data directories the file is only available throug your app and will be deleted if you uninstall your app.

the purpose of a contentprovider is that you can read content from any uri as inputStream (i.e. form "uri= "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...", "file:///storage/emulated/0/...", "ftp:....", "content:...") as long as there is a provider for this.

with api 25 Google enforces that "file:..." uri-s are not allowed any more

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to keep the files "private" and I want it to be deleted once the app is uninstalled. I only want my app to be able to access the files unless when I want to share the files from within y application.

Comment: for private files you need either a contentprovider or a documentProvider

Comment: Ok thank you. My minimum SDK is 16, should I check if SDK is 19< and then perform with the old way by using `file://`?

Comment: that depends on your client apps that receive the image. some can handle file:// some can handle content:// and some can handle both. use https://github.com/k3b/intent-intercept/ and https://github.com/k3b/ContentProviderHelper/ to analyse intents and contentprovider. my [imageapp](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki) can handle both and will soon get a config setting wther to expose file:// or content:// where default will be content://

Comment: and it only gets more complicated.. Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question.

Comment: Last night I started thinking about your last comment. By the end of the month all apps should target 24+, so doesn't that mean that from the end of the month most apps will be able to handle `content://`? That was the point of forcing app developers to target 24+ in the first place, for security?

Comment: if the the send-receiver are all programmed by you, yes. if you use apps that where last modified 4 years ago it means no. when in doubt you should use "content:". after rethinking this topic: my app currently uses send/view via "file" and i will make an incompatible change to "content:" without config page. that means less programming, less gui elements less userdocumentation.